# Creating an array of all substrings of a string

Tags: java, arraylist

How can I create a `List` or `ArrayList` of all substrings of a given string?
For example, if my input is "test", then I need an  array = {"t", "e", "s", "t", "te", "es", "st", "tes", "est", "test"}.

Comment: Did you try writing any code ?

Comment: This is not how SO works, asking for code directly. Try out something yourself and then ask a specific question.

Comment: can you check this link http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-program-find-substrings-of-string hope this is useful for you..

Comment: Please provide your code you worked on.

Comment: you should have worked it out yourself but still you can check this link http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-program-find-substrings-of-string

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to comment here. I did fix the problem afterwards with some googling. Sorry :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to generating permutations given a number "N". So find the length of the string first and iterate and generate the substrings

Something like this-

```
Algorithm-
for i=0 to string.length
   for j=1 to string.length-i
       //Generate substrings here
```

As others have suggested make some attempt to solve the problem and then ask your doubt!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code if you want to use `ArrayList` as it is dynamic:

```
    String input = "test";
    String temp;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=(input.length()-i);j++){
            temp = input.substring(i,i+j);
            list.add(temp);

        }
    }
    for (String string : list) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
```

If you still want to use array of String , you can do like this:

```
String input = "test";
        String temp;
        String[] list = new String[10];
        int k=0;
        for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++){
            for(int j=1;j<=(input.length()-i);j++){
                temp = input.substring(i,i+j);
                list[k++]=temp;

            }
        }
        for (String string : list) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
```

**Note: Better to use ArrayList than array as ArrayList is dynamic.**

Comment: Please try this one and let me know if you still have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution for your problem.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Substrings {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        ArrayList<String> substrings = Substrings.generateSubstrings("test");
        for(String s : substrings)
            System.out.println(s);

    }

    public static ArrayList<String> generateSubstrings(String str) {
        //The total number of substrings of given string
        int substringsCount = str.length() * (str.length() + 1) / 2;

        ArrayList<String> substrings = new ArrayList<String>(substringsCount);

        //generating all the substrings.
        for(int i = 0;i < str.length();i++)
            for(int j = i+1;j <= str.length();j++)
                substrings.add(str.substring(i,j));

        return substrings;
    }
}
```